# Select value with CSV parser

Tags: c#, parsing, csv

I am grabbing a value at a time and dynamically loading it into a grid.

Is there a way to index a csv file to only look up a value at a certain row and column?
I can't read all the rows as that would defeat the purpose of loading dynamically.

The CSV parser, [Fast CSV Parser](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) in my case, can grab a value like so `csv[row][column]`. When looking at the source, I noticed that it loops over everything in the file until it reaches the correct index column pair. To grab a value at row 100,000 column 80, it can take quite a long time.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could do a fast first pass and store the offsets of each row.  That would make subsequently locating a row much faster.  If you have 80 columns but 100K rows, I'd focus on fast row-finding rather than fast column-finding.

ETA:  OK, I'm assuming your CSV file is on disk and that you can get exclusive access to it.  Some of this code was based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201414/using-filestream-seek).

```
   List<int> offsets = new List<int>();
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("myfile.csv"))
   {
        int offset = 0;
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {   
            offsets.Add(offset);             
            offset += (line.Length + 2);   // The 2 is for NewLine(\r\n)
        }
        offsets.Add(offset);  // pick up the last one
    }
```

At the end of this, you will have the List variable `offsets`, which is indexed by line number and contains the offset to each line.  You can then, when reading the file (when doing your grid-building) use `offsets[n]` to get the offset to `Seek` to (I'm assuming you're using a FileStream or a StreamReader) and `offsets[n+1] - offsets[n]` to get the length.

As far as parsing the returned line of text is concerned, I assume the CSV library you're adapting has good logic for that.

Comment: If I were able to index them, how would I do it? Also how would I then say give me the row at this index? Is each row likely to be the same length in bytes and hence I say for row 18 give me sizeof(row)*18 and then how would I say to start at that byte length and read the row?

Comment: @EvilWeebl  I'll fill out my answer with some suggestions.

Comment: That looks great! Thanks a lot I'll be sure to have a play with that.

Answer (score 0):

CSV files do not have any support for indexing where a particular row might be, no.

The best I think you can do is read each row until you find the one you want. So you'll average reading half the file when scanning for a row, which is better than reading the entire file.

If you use the CSV parser I present in the article [Reading and Writing CSV Files in C#](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/files/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-c), you can just read one row at a time.

The other option is if you are going to be accessing multiple rows from the same file. In this case, you could run through the file and build a list of indexes. But this only pays off if your going to lookup multiple lines in a single session.

Comment: Currently I'm grabbing actual values one by one as I'm using unbound column in a grid and fetching the values for the column and row when requested, not very efficient I know. not so bad when its requesting row 10 column 5 since it only reads that far but if your looking for all 6 column data values in row 10000 that means it needs to read 10000 rows each time it needs to get a value which as you can imagine is slow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are permitted to use 3rd party libraries I'd look at some of those.  MySQL has CSV engine support and therefor it seems likely that you'd be able to do this using a library from them.

C# however doesn't provide a great way to handle CSV files.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html